# Rule of thumb on how to run a set of optimization algorithms

Tags: algorithm, optimization, compiler-optimization

My compiler supports the following common optimization algorithms:

- Constant Propagation.
- Copy propagation.
- Common sub-expression elimination.
- Algebraic Simplification.
- Constant Folding.
- Useless code elimination.

I have a program that I want to do optimizations to. I was wondering if there is a rule of thumb on what would be the best way to run those optimizations. I could run them differently and they will lead to different result. What would be a good rule of thumb on how to use them in order to mostly get to best optimization (minimal code).

Comment: Run them all, then repeatedly until the code doesn't change anymore.

Comment: All answers to this question will be extremely opinionbased which unfortunately makes this question off topic. In my compiler I do all of these between each of the more advanced optimizations, to clean up code.